# AWS Cloudformation support for EKS Fargate

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I had come across some examples of Cloudformation for EKS (NOT ecs) using Fargate.   It appears none of this is actually supported by AWS and what I found were in fact proposals.

Can someone confirm?   Is this the ticket to track its implementation?  https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/288

Is everyone using the SDK APIs to programatically accomplish deployments?  ouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this recent post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/eks-supports-creation-management-fargate-profiles-aws-cloudformation/), EKS with Fargate profiles is now supported via CloudFormation. I've not had a chance to try it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a Lambda function and use it within your Cloud Formation.